# Port Delphi.NET (ASP.NET 1.1) Project to ASP.NET 3.5 using C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-1.1, delphi.net

i have an ASP.NET project written in Delphi.NET with Borland Studio 2006. Well it seems that the .NET Version is 1.1 and i need to port it to 3.5. My problem is that the project is a .bdsgroup and .groupproj. To make my work comfortable, i'd like to get a solution file .sln. What's the best way to this? (im not really sure i'm doing it all the right way. so if you have suggestions to make the port better, i'd please you to tell me)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets get a few things straightened out. Delphi.NET is both a language and a set of runtime libraries which attempted to recreate the RTL/VCL on the .NET platform.

Borland Development Studio is an IDE designed to edit multiple languages: Delphi, C++, C#, Delphi.NET.

If your intention is to port a Delphi.NET application to C# there are a few tools you can use. RedGate's .NET Reflector can generate C# from any .NET assembly regardless of the language that was used to write the assembly. I found it to be fairly useful at converting a Delphi.NET application to C#. Note: The generated code will still have dependencies on the RTL/VCL so you will still have to replace these with standard .NET equivalents.

If you are doing a Borland C# to VS C# port at least you're already in the same language. You'll just have to deal with library dependencies for the most part. If you already have the code working in BDS 2006 you can save yourself some trouble by replacing any borland-specific dependencies with standard .NET ones before you move to Visual Studio.

With proper separation of concerns and wrappers around third party libaries this is fairly straightforward. Unfortunately this is rarely the case. If your project is like most RAD style projects the business logic is embedded directly into the UI and library dependencies are directly woven into your code (this is rampant on any platform so don't think I'm singling out fans of Borland/Inprise/Codegear/Embarcadero). If this is the case you have your work cut out for you.

Answer (score 0):

.sln file is Visual studio file, and not related to .Net or asp.net.

Delphi .Net has only support for .Net v2 (Delphi 2007), but you can switch your project to Delphi prism which support .Net up to verion 4, and work also from Visual studio IDE.

**UPDATE:**

I didn't know at first you are using C# project, so I gave my answer as Delphi, but if your project is c#, you can simply start VS and create new blank project, then add the *.cs from Project menu > add Exiting Files and point the *.CS files inside Delphi project, then save the Visual studio Project.

VS Doesn't read the *.bdsgroup files.

Comment: well delphi prism isnt free like i see... so i dont think that its the solution for my problem. There must be another way to get my asp.net project written in borland studio 2006 to Visual Studio

Comment: You can compile your code to DLL Assembly and use it with VS, but there's no way to convert your d2006 project to VS, except if you rewrite it using C#.

Comment: i have asp.net with c# codebehind... it was just made in borland studio 2006... i think the only difference is that it is not a .sln, just a .bdsproj

Comment: @ your Update: its not as easy as you describe, i got 109 Exceptions after that :) that was the first i was trying

Comment: the project seems to contain many settings, references, 3 different SOAP services

Comment: It's very hard to tell how it will work without seeing it, but I gave you general idea about how you can convert, but every project has it's own way.